# PCA in production - use with incoming data

Tags: pca

I have a large training dataset that I used to fit a model. Before fitting the model I applied PCA. Now the model is fit and ready to be deployed to production, where it will make predictions one observation at a time. My question is, what is the appropriate way to transform the incoming *n* variables to the PCA reduced set *m*?

EDIT: minimal code example showing that mean subtraction is required

```
# using sklearn 0.21
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

#dummy data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
transformed_data = pca.fit_transform(df)
array([[-0.09150808,  0.10412935],
       [-0.03471536, -0.41757135],
       [-0.42427325, -0.19299645],
       [ 0.76549898, -0.26305905],
       [-0.62059276, -0.02702175],
       [ 0.26488503, -0.09145729],
       [-0.27959735,  0.24832636],
       [-0.01023595, -0.29202606],
       [ 0.4358998 ,  0.43832102],
       [-0.00536107,  0.49335522]])

transformed_no_mean = df.dot(pca.components_.T)
              0         1
        0 -0.334199 -0.832622
        1 -0.277407 -1.354323
        2 -0.666965 -1.129748
        3  0.522808 -1.199811
        4 -0.863284 -0.963773
        5  0.022194 -1.028209
        6 -0.522289 -0.688425
        7 -0.252927 -1.228778
        8  0.193209 -0.498431
        9 -0.248052 -0.443396


transformed_with_mean = (df-pca.mean_).dot(pca.components_.T)
              0         1
        0 -0.091508  0.104129
        1 -0.034715 -0.417571
        2 -0.424273 -0.192996
        3  0.765499 -0.263059
        4 -0.620593 -0.027022
        5  0.264885 -0.091457
        6 -0.279597  0.248326
        7 -0.010236 -0.292026
        8  0.435900  0.438321
        9 -0.005361  0.493355
```

Comment: You can check the 'reusable principle component analysis' section for a scikit-learn solution: https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-principal-component-analysis-scratch-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should calculate the *eigenvectors* corresponding the the $m$ Principal Components that you chose to keep based on the training dataset. And then use those eigenvectors to transform your new sample (in production) onto the new subspace.

For example, let's assume you chose to keep the top two principal components, so $m=2$. And your input data contains 100 rows and 5 columns, so $n=5$.

The set of eigenvectors is your "projection matrix" and it would look something like this:

$$
W = \left[
\matrix
{
w_{1,1}&w_{1,2} \\
w_{2,1}&w_{2,2} \\
w_{3,1}&w_{3,2} \\
w_{4,1}&w_{4,2} \\
w_{5,1}&w_{5,2}
}
\right]
$$

Notice that there are *two* eigenvactors because we decided to keep the top *two* principal components. And there are *five* total values for each eigenvector, each one corresponding to one of the *five* columns in the original dataset.

Your input dataset would look something like this:

$$
X = \left[
\matrix
{
x_{1,1}&x_{1,2}&x_{1,3}&x_{1,4}&x_{1,5} \\
x_{2,1}&...&...&...&x_{2,5} \\
...&...&...&...&... \\
x_{100,1}&x_{100,2}&x_{100,3}&x_{100,4}&x_{100,5}
}
\right]
$$

You can use the simple formula below to transform your input sample onto the new subspace:

$$
Y = X \times W
$$

$Y$ will be your $100 \times 2$ matrix of the transformed sample.

Although there's no theoretical need for this, in most software the transformed data is centered (normalized to the mean). You can subtract the means of each column from $Y$ so that the results match with the results from a software function such as `.fit_transform()` in Python's scikit-learn package.

Keep in mind that if you standardized your training data prior to performing PCA (e.g., mean=0 and standard deviation=1), then you'd have to do the same before applying the transformation formula mentioned above.

Comment: I was able to replicate the rotation of the training data from the above with the exception that I had to first subtract out the mean of the data. I can accept your answer if you add that step, as I don't want others to find this post and miss that step.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you. You would have to subtract the mean _only if_ you had done that during the training process, prior to performing PCA.  Similarly, if you had standardized your data (mean=0, std dev=1) prior to performing PCA, then you'd have to repeat _that_ step in production. I had already mentioned that in my original answer.

Comment: I added code showing that even without mean subtracting the original data it appears to be required to replicate the pca results.

Comment: That's useful; thanks for adding the code. The transformed data based on PCA is often centered (normalized to the mean) in modern software such as Python (scikit-learn) and R (prcomp). However, this is not always the case; it's a practical convention and there's no theoretical need for this. I will happily add that in my answer, so it is clear to others who might stumble on this page in future.

Answer (score 0):

You used `fit_transform()` function which fits then transforms the training data. Instead, you can just do `fit()` to fit the `pca` object to train data, then apply `transform()` to a *new* input data. Obviously, make sure that the new dataframe has the same exact structure as the one you used to fit the PCA

Comment: How would this work in a production process? You'd would have to either retain the original training data, load it in the program, run `fit()` and `transform()` sequentially on training and scoring (new) samples respectively. Or, you could retain the trained PCA _object_ itself, e.g., in Python, you can save the object by using `joblib.dump()` and then load it using `joblib.load()`. OTOH, the approach I mentioned uses the actual values from the eigenvector, which can be hard-coded in the scoring program, eliminating dependencies on the training sample or the trained (fitted) object.

Comment: @Vishal, you only retain `pca` object, not the train data frame. If you really want to optimize then copy `pca.components_` and mean, then drop the parent object `pca`. the details of production deployment are clearly out of scope of this forum, and belong to SE.